# Enterprise license required for modifying workflow initiation forms?

Tags: 2013, infopath, designer-workflow, licensing

We're running a **SharePoint Server 2013 Standard** farm with Standard CALs for all users. Within a few site collections we're using ootb list workflows (2010 engine; no reusable workflows).

For some workflows we modify the standard initiation form (`.xsn`) via SharePoint Designer (InfoPath opens up respectively) to add some text or some validation logic.

Do we break the SharePoint Server 2013 Standard license agreement by modifying these ootb forms using InfoPath?

I've found answers on SP.SE regarding SharePoint 2010 [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/57858/18923) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/15631/18923) and an answer regarding [modifying SharePoint 2013 list forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/81080/18923). The answers are very different.

I'm looking for **official sources** for SharePoint 2013 on this topic (TechNet, MSDN, etc.).